# How to create shareable libraries for Desktop, Web and Mobile Apps (Electron.JS, Angular, NativeScript)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, libraries

Can anyone guide me for how to create separate libraries for models (Reusable Libraries)?

For example,

If I want to create web, desktop and mobile app, so I required models and services files in all projects to communicate with my API.

I required to models in all projects (Server, Web, Mobile and Desktop App) and Services which can communicate with node.js API (web, Mobile and Desktop App). I don'n want to create files in all project, instead of this I want to create one shareable libraries for models and functions.

Can you guide me how to achieve this type of project structure OR best suitable architecture.

I am a Microsoft Stack developer. So, I can follow this structure in .net but how can I achieve this using node.js or TypeScript?

Comment: I think creating an npm pkg would be suitable for your use case

Comment: Can you please explain more about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a node module which will be reusable by any project using node run-time.
For a basic understanding, go through a medium article

[How to Easily Share Reusable Modules in Node.js - at Scale](https://medium.com/hackernoon/how-to-easily-share-reusable-modules-in-node-js-at-scale-daaab9f0f41d)

Note: I'm not an author/promoter of this medium article.